# Como puedo sumar elementos repetidos de un array en python 3

Tags: python

lo que pasa es que necesito que me aparezca algo así de una arreglo en Numpy de canciones con sus reproducciones.

```
[[‘broken bones’ ‘30’]
 [‘broken bones’ ‘40’]
 ‘End game’ ‘30’]]
```

Yo quiero saber como hacer para que me salga algo así:

```
[[‘broken bones’ ‘70’]
 [‘End game’ ‘30’]]
```

Es decir, que se sumen las reproducciones de las canciones repetidas, y las que no se repiten, dejarlas como están.

Por favor, si alguien me ayuda sería muy genial, gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías poner qué has intentado hasta ahora? Por otro lado, el ejemplo que muestras de arreglo en numpy, no es código válido. Quiero decir, que si copio y pego tu ejemplo en un programa python me dará error pues no usas el caracter de comillas adecuado ni separas los elementos por comas. Además no creo que numpy sea la herramienta adecuada pues tus arrays contienen mezcla de cadenas y números.

Comment: Pequeño detalle. Python no utiliza arrays, por diseño. Lo que tienes ahí arriba se llaman listas. No es que sea importante pero siempre viene bien usar la terminología correcta.

Comment: @Saelyth de hecho, la librería en cuestión implementa un array, es por eso que se llama `numpy.array`.